# Sorting list according to nested list

Tags: nested-lists

`joinedlist = [['B', 'C', 'A'], ['D', 'C', 'F'], ['E', 'E', 'D'], ['C', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'D', 'D']]`

And I want to sort the first nested loop

`['A', 'B', 'C']`

So the order of the remaining nested loops is sorted in that order according to the first list (3,1,2) so I get this output:

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
zip(*sorted(zip(*joinedlist)))
```

`zip(*joinedlist)` makes a list of tuples of matching elements from the inner lists:

```
[('B', 'D', 'E', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'E', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'F', 'D', 'E', 'D')]
```

This then get sorted by the leading elements of the lists, which are the elements from the first original sub-list, so corresponding elements each get moved as a group.

Finally, we take that result and re-zip it, to get things broken up as before but now properly sorted.